# Zend framework 2 PDF generation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, pdf-generation

I want to crate single A5 PDF document with 24 pages , There is no need to account for slugs or bleed  , What is the Best Zendframwork 2 PDF generation Module for this ? Do you have tutorials or example pleas send me the links

thank you ..

Answer (score 1):

I use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/index.php).

To get it up and running within your Zf2 installation you have to add a litle extra to your `composer.json`. It should look something like this.

```
{
  "name": "...
  "description": "...",
  "require": {
      "php": ">=5.4",
      ....
      "tecnick.com/tcpdf": ">=6.0.043"
      ....
  },
  "repositories": [{
       "type":"package",
       "package": {
           "name": "tecnick.com/tcpdf",
           "version":"master",
           "source": {
                "url": "http://git.code.sf.net/p/tcpdf/code",
                "type": "git",
                "reference":"master"
           }
       }
  }],
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf"
    ]
  }
}
```

The `"autoload"` functionality here will create a few entries within your `autoload_classmap.php` in your vendor/composer path.

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
...
   'TCPDF' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php',
   'TCPDF2DBarcode' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php',
   'TCPDFBarcode' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf_barcodes_1d.php',
   'TCPDF_COLORS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_colors.php',
   'TCPDF_FILTERS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_filters.php',
   'TCPDF_FONTS' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_fonts.php',
   'TCPDF_FONT_DATA' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_font_data.php',
   'TCPDF_IMAGES' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_images.php',
   'TCPDF_IMPORT' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf_import.php',
   'TCPDF_PARSER' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf_parser.php',
   'TCPDF_STATIC' => $vendorDir . '/tecnick.com/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php',
...
);
```

At this point you can just create a Pdf Object or use the other defiened Classes to your liking.

```
//to create a Pdf Object
$pdf = new \TCPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Sadly the TCPDF website is not quite the looker nor is it clear to find things there (in my opinion). But it does provide quite a few [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) which cover quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

that all depends on a few things;

how much control you need over the PDF
Are you able to install php extensions?
Are you making the PDF from scratch, or converting other formats etc

There's some on packagist.org, which are easily installable via composer, and one which will work with ZF2 components:

```
https://github.com/psliwa/PHPPdf/tree/master
```