# Zend Framework 2 Include

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using a php module that uses an include statement in the view.  How do I include this file using the MVC model?  My current structure is listed below.  I would like to include the Foo file from the model.  Previously all the files were in the same folder and the view referenced include_once(foo.php).  I have tried a few different paths in an attempt to reference the foo file but to no success so far.

```
Calendar
   Controller
   Model
     Foo
   Form
   View
     calendar
       calendar
         index
```

Thank you
M

Comment: I once included tcpdf in my application via composer. which you can find here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774157/zend-framework-2-pdf-generation/19786793#19786793 . I did not post this as an answer since at this points it's unclear as to what kind of module this is nor the way you aquired it(composer, normal downlaod unzip etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//use this 
include realpath(__DIR__.'/../../../Model/Foo.php');

//The first .. moves you to parent directory of index file (View->calendar->calendar)
//The second .. gets you to the parent directory of caldendar direcory(View->calendar)
//The third .. gets you to the parent directory of View directory
//from here you can move to Model directory
//I hope it helps
```